# What is the meaning of "umhängbar"?

Tags: single-word-request

I've unsuccessfully googled it and looked for the meaning of this word, that I have to interpret in the following phrase: 
"Meine Anforderungen - nicht zu groß, günstig, mit Rollen zum Hinterherziehen, viele Seitentaschen und sie muss umhängbar sein."

Comment: "muss umhängbar sein" --> "must have shoulder straps".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The suffix *-bar* used in German adjectives is the about the same as *-able* or *-ible* in English, with the meaning *possible*, or *fit.*

In this case

> umhängbar

means that you can wear or hang an object on your shoulder or around your neck. The verb is *[umhängen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/umhaengen_herunterhaengen).*

Usually it's referred to bags as in

> Die Tasche ist aus Stoff und umhängbar.

[image: Umhängbare Tasche]
<sub>([Photo](http://www.flickr.com/photos/zutaten/3758685794/) by [zutaten](http://www.flickr.com/photos/zutaten/))</sub>

*Note:* Though there are many "established" -bar words, but some of them (neologisms) are considered bad style ([see this article](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-im-bann-des-silbenbarbaren-a-285626.html)).

Words with the suffix -bar are often used in descriptions of commercial products, for example

- umtauschbare Ware (returnable)
- aufladbare Batterien (rechargable)

Comment: Das musst du mir erklären, wo das Problem mit den -bar Wörtern ist. Versteh ich nicht und ist auch gar nicht relevant im Kontext.

Comment: @Em1 "ersteigerbar", "kaufbar", "uneintauschbar" (würg); bin zwar nicht ein Zwiebelfischfan, aber hier ein Beitrag, der beschreibt, was ich meinte: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-im-bann-des-silbenbarbaren-a-285626.html

Comment: Naja, mit nur einer Ausnahme würde ich alle Beispiele in dem Beitrag instinktiv nicht mit dem -bar Wort sagen; und iwie ist mir dieser "Trend" bisher verborgen geblieben. Im Falle von *umhängbar* würde ich zwar zum Infinitv greifen oder Substantivierung, aber abwegig finde ich das Wort nicht. Die Worte die du noch nennst, sind in der Tat grässlich, aber *umtauschbar* (wieder besser Infintiv o. Substantivierung) klingt für mich akzteptierbar...äh akzeptabel natürlich :D

Comment: @Em1 Also ist meine Antwort *upvotebar*, weil sie *verstehbar* ist. ;-)

Comment: Euer Dialog ist beschmunzelbar

Comment: PS: Habe die Kritik an -bar-Wörtern etwas entschärft.

Answer (score 0):

**able to hang over** (someone's shoulder)

> My requirements - not too big, low price, with pull-behind rollers, lots of side pockets and it must be **able to hang over** my shoulder.

Comment: *Hang over*? I did, last weekend ;)

Comment: Can a bag be able to do something? "... and I must be able to hang it over", oder nicht? Die Tasche hat nicht die Fähigkeit, umhängbar zu sein, sondern eine Eigenschaft.

Answer (score -2):

The word is in style and meaning as good as:

> hangable

Comment: I believe *"hangable"* translates better to *"aufhängbar"*.

Comment: yes, also true. Equally dumb though :)